# JS - jQuery class interfaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, interface

Does jQuery class support interfaces that must be implemented by a class like Java does?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? What is "jQuery class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JavaScript is a dynamic language interfaces would not normally be used, there's more info in this question -

[Are Interfaces in JavaScript necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419626/are-interfaces-in-javascript-necessary)

There was a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059908X) released some time ago that looked at implementing constructs like interfaces in JavaScript. Here's a post from the blog of one of the book's authors that specifically deals with implementing interfaces -

http://www.dustindiaz.com/roll-out-your-own-interface/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no classes, so I think that short answer is **no**

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this:[js-Interface](https://github.com/wbpmrck/js-Interface)

It can help you to write the 'interface patten' in javascript .it's very easy